# HTML + CSS tab bar

Tags: html, css, tabs

How do I cleanly style a HTML + CSS horizontal tab bar so that the tab bar has a line across the bottom that's hidden or suppressed for the active tab?

In other words, I'm trying to do the same thing that StackOverflow does for its tags:
[image]

My tab bar is set up as an ordered list with

```
ul
{
  list-style: none;
}
li
{
  float: left;
}
```

**Update**:  I've already poked around sites with Firebug to see how they do it, but I feel like I quickly get bogged down in details.  For example, StackOverflow's version has a border for the bottom of the whole div (which makes sense), and a white border for the bottom of the active tab (which makes sense), but then it makes the active tab's border overlap the div's border (and I'm not very clear on how it does that).  It looks like [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navs) does something similar.  I'm trying to understand the general concept of how overlapping part of a container's border with the content's border works instead of copying and tinkering with CSS until I get something that appears to work.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Or getting code from StackOverflow's css at least?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is put a bottom border on the `<ul>` (so that it stretches across) and then give the `<li>`'s a selected class, and make that one have a 1-pixel higher height.

Here is a very simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/V6gzS/

Answer (score 0):

ok to point you in the right direction use firebug or chromes element inspector and just pick out the bits you need, so on this site for example what you are looking for are called tabs and they are styled like so

```
#tabs a.youarehere {
background: #fff;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
color: black;
font-size: 120%;
height: 30px;
line-height: 28px;
margin-top: 3px;
padding: 0px 11px 0px 11px;
 }
```

this is just a part of it but you can learn a lot by looking at some code

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you are capable of making the buttons by yourself, with the horizontal bottom line.

If that is the case, then make sure that this horizontal line is made as a `border-bottom: solid 1px #CCC` property on each button (the color might be different). At each page you then add the id `id="current"` to that one button that is the active page. In CSS you write:

```
#current {
  border: solid 1px #CCC;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
```

If you have any problems it might be solved by adding `!important` like this:

```
  border-bottom: 1px solid white !important;
```

Therefore, this is just four extra lines of code in CSS and one extra HTML attribute in each of the files.

**If dynamic menu**

If you have a menu that is not static on every page, but maybe dynamically generated or placed in an included file, then the above will not be possible. Because then you can't easily add the new id on each seperate page.

In that case you might do some dynamic adding of the attribute. If a server side language is used, e.g. PHP, then you might be able to easily set up an `if{...}` command that checks the URL or a GET request or alike. Else you might use some javascript to check each button and add the attribute `id` if the button text equals some header on the page.

I hope you understand. Good luck.

Comment: What if I want the border to extend across the entire tab bar (and not just where each button / tab happens to be)?

Comment: @JoshKelley. I'm not sure I understand what you mean.  
How will you create the grafics that you show in the picture in your question, if the border is extended further than the buttons width? What  should the vertical borders do then?

Comment: @Steven - I want the tab bar's border to extend the width of the screen or parent (like SO and Twitter Bootstrap), even if the tab buttons don't extend the width of the screen.  I'm still vague on hwo to do this; if I give each tab an opaque border (as you said), then the border doesn't extend the width of the screen, and if I give the whole tab bar a bottom border, then the active tab;s white bottom border sits above the border instead of replacing it.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
}
li{
    float: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
}
li:hover{
    float: left;
    border: solid 1px #CCC;
    border-bottom:none;
}
```